Non-turbulent flow seen in the wake of an obstruction
For a project, a group I'm involved in, is trying to demonstrate the effect of characteristic length in the Reynold's Number. The flow of water was obstructed with two cylinders of different diameter, and food dye was injected upstream. The hypothesis was that turbulence would be more visible in the wake of the larger cylinder.
When we ran the experiment, there were some vortices visible at the point of flow separation at the edge of the cylinder, however, in watching the videos, one is struck by the highly regular non-turbulent flow seen in the wake of the cylinder. Food dye that separates from the cylinder travels down the channel very quickly, but this band of regular flow forms later and persists for quite a while.
Is this flow indeed laminar? How is it explained in the context of the Reynold's number? If it is indeed less turbulent than the wake of a smaller obstruction as our experiment suggests, is the characteristic length for this flow related to the gap between the cylinder and the channel walls, that has indeed gotten narrower? Or is it purely a consequence of the reduced speed of this flow, in which case it's characteristic length is described by the width of the flow on the far side of the cylinder, however this is counter-intuitive as the greater this dimension is, the lower the turbulence appears to be. Any insight or guidance is greatly appreciated.


